# Как вернуть элементы массива?

Tags: java, методы

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Создаём массив целых чисел
        int[] number = new int[15];

        System.out.println(randomArray(number));
    }

    public static int[] randomArray(int num[]) {
        Random rn = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            num[i] = rn.nextInt(20);
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

Данный метод не возвращает элементы, возвращает только адрес на массив.
Как можно вернуть все элементы?

Comment: а что,  println  способна напечатать содержимое массива? похоже, метод тут ни при чём.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] number = new int[15];
randomArray(number);
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(number));
```

Arrays.toString() позволяет вывести массив в виде строки, но если вам нужно вывести массив с помощью метода, то вместо массива можно возвращать строку с помощью Arrays.toString, либо выводить элементы массива с помощью другого цикла, либо одно временно с инициализацией элементов выводить массив